# Bypass encryption by altering source code

Tags: encryption, source-code, luks

In the Cryptsetup Frequently Asked Questions page it says:

> You are asked a passphrase of an existing key-slot first, before you can enter the passphrase for the new key-slot. Otherwise you could break the encryption by just adding a new key-slot.

Is it not possible to edit the cryptsetup source code to delete this verification step, so that it is possible to bypass the encryption by adding a new key-slot? I've looked at the source code, but it's beyond my programming ability to be able to answer this question myself. I'm sure the answer is obvious.

Comment: "I'm sure the answer is obvious."  No it's not. no answer is obvious,  same with dumb questions -  there are just dumb answers!  I have thought about this too, I think it would be possible to (at least, add a new key slot) or, a hook in any case (as with the LUKS nuke-hook option) **EDIT:  does *hooking* count as a answer?** (so,  it looks like 1 keyslot (if it was 1 originally)  but if (say) another password/or key (or any other means of authentication) was entered it would unlock it  
Note: I do not mean using a LUKS-Nuke-Like hook, I think that was clear but, better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that the explanation you cite is correct. A key slot just provides access to the master key of the volume - see [LUKS multiple key slots - what's the intuition?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24022/luks-multiple-key-slots-whats-the-intuition). Thus adding a new key slot for an existing encrypted volume means that the current master key needs to be retrieved first, before it can be encrypted for the new key slot. To retrieve the master key one need to get it from one of the existing key slots first, which needs the matching passphrase in order to decrypt the encrypted master key.